# PostgreSQL versus MySQL for EAV structures storage

Tags: database-design, postgresql, performance, mysql-5, eav

Is there any practical difference or what are the advantages of using Postgres 9.x versus MySQL 5.x for storing [EAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-Attribute-Value_model) (Entity-Attribute-Value) structures, especially in terms of read performance?

Comment: EAV is almost universally an anti pattern that can and should be avoided if at all possible. I recommend Bill Karwin's SQL Anti  as a book that discusses this exact issue.

Comment: EAV is sometimes useful, particularly when your data isn't very relational.  For example, storing arguments for shell scripts to be called ;-)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Both excel at a simple task like this. If you end up having big queries where you search for entities that share many attributes ("[relational division](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/)"), I would expect PostgreSQL at an advantage for its superior [index handling](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/indexes.html).

In particular, multiple joins can be combined with bitmap index scans - a feature that is not present in MySQL. It has an ["index_merge"](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/index-merge-optimization.html) feature to substitute for that.

For PostgreSQL you may also be interested in the [`hstore` extension](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/hstore.html) for storing sets of key/value pairs.

Comment: +1 for hstore. It is amazingly fast when using an index on the column.

Comment: You can add that MySQL has a hard limit (61) on how many tables can be joined in a query.

Comment: Also, I would add that PostgreSQL has some very useful functions for making EAV work in a sane manner (like array_agg, unnest, and the like).  The sorts of areas we use EAV for in LedgerSMB (settings, next-in-series stuff, menu script arguments, etc) are all areas where the data is actually perfect for EAV and these functions come in very useful there.  I expect to be using hstore more in the future in these cases.